# Transforming a payload from requestjs before sending it to the client

Tags: node.js, json, api, express, requestjs

Brothers and sisters, I am building an Express API Endpoint that needs to consume an external API, perform some changing of keys and values, and return to the result to the client.  Here is what I have thus far:

```
const external_endpoint = <external_api_end_point>;

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

  request({ url: external_endpoint}).pipe(res);
});
```

This returns the exact payload you would get from hitting the `external_endpoint` directly.

Isn't there something I can do to change `res` before it gets sent to the client?  I tried a few things but nothings has worked.  Any ideas or best practices associated with doing a transform on the incoming payload?

For the sake of simplicity.  Lets say this is the payload `obj.json`:

```
{
    "sad": {
        "userid": 5,
        "username": "jsmith",
        "isAdmin": true
    }
}
```

and I am wanting to change `sad` to `happy`.

I know outside of the request I could do something like this:

```
obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).split('"sad":').join('"happy":'));
```

but throwing `obj` in place of `res` will not work.  I have tried assigning the value of this `res` and `res.body` but no dice.

Thanks for you help in advance!

Comment: Can you clarify what ```request``` is?  There are multiple libraries this could be.

Comment: right.  Sorry for not clarifying this.  I am using `request ^2.88.0`.  Here is the link to the github repo for it https://github.com/request/request

Comment: Got it.  Yes, the basic ```request``` module handles streaming to express responses as a first class citizen.  So you could use the ```event-stream``` method I outline in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `request-promise`, you can simply make a new response and send it, or modify the response you got back:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {    
    request({ url: external_endpoint, json: true})
        .then(response => res.json({ happy: response.sad })))
        .catch(next);
});
```

(of course, you need to handle errors appropriately)

If you want to process it as a stream (which makes sense if you have a massive amount of data), you can use the original `request` module, and use `event-stream` to create your pipe:

```
const es = require('event-stream');

const swapper = es.through(
    function write(data) {
        this.emit("data", data.replace("sad", "happy"));
    },
    function end() {
        this.emit("end");
    }
);

request({ url: external_endpoint})
    .pipe(es.stringify())
    .pipe(swapper)
    .pipe(es.parse())
    .pipe(res);
```

Here's a sandbox to test the stream processing: https://codesandbox.io/s/3wqx67pq6

Comment: In the code above  using `await` you need to add `async` just prior to the function or await will return as undefined.

Comment: So on the `.pipe(es.map(j => j.replace('sad', 'happy'))` it would seem like we are missing a closing `)`.  However even when I add this to the end of the line it doesn't work as expected.  I tried adding to the end of `.pipe(res))` it returns the payload but without any replacing going on.

Comment: Indeed, ```es.map()``` isn't right because we're receiving a string at that point.  Replaced with ```es.through()```

Comment: BTW, had trouble with the codesandbox link, but I think it's working now.

Comment: Awesome but looking to make this just a little better.   Say Someone has the word `sad` in their username(or in any value for that matter).  Whats to prevent or ensure that this `.replace` wont change that value?  I attempted to change the `data.replace("sad", "happy")` to `data.replace('"sad":', '"happy":')` but including quotes seems to break the replace from working at all.  Any ideas on how I can target just changing keys instead of data?  You have been a huge help thus far.  Thanks for everything.

Comment: Just answered my own questions.  `.replace` supports the use of regular expressions.  This means that I could user a regular expression, something like   And to further ensure that I don't replace something I don't intend I can use a regular expression as it appears that `.replace` supports the use of regular expressions.  However when testing with something like `"sad":` or even `/"user":/` . It fails to replace though I fairly confident my regex is correct.  Any ideas on this?

Comment: Might be a topic for another question.  Regexes are powerful but tricky.  I recommend breaking it down and using node in REPL mode to debug.

Comment: agreed.  Thats I why I marked this as answered.  Thanks again!